# Retrive query strings of previous page

Tags: php, query-string

assume we click on a `link` in page `page1.php?id=1` and go to `page2.php`.
My question is that: How can I retrieve value of `id` on `page1.php` in `page2.php`?

Comment: You can't get `id` of previous page. One alternativa is that your page1 links to `page2?id=1` so you have the id also available on `page2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In page1.php  set the id value in a 
`$_SESSION['pageid']=$_GET['id']`

den retrive `$_SESSION['pageid']` in page2.php and as soon as u access the id value unset the session `unset($_SESSION['pageid'])`